# django multiple views file

Tags: python, django, file, view

I separate my views into some files.

so say I have this:

```
website/
│   manage.py
│
├───app
│   │   admin.py
│   │   admin.pyc
│   │   models.py
│   │   models.pyc
│   │   tests.py
│   │   views.py
│   │   views.pyc
│   │   views_home.py
│   │   views_home.pyc
│   │   __init__.py
│   │   __init__.pyc
│   │
│   └───templates
│
├───locale
│
│
└───website
        settings.py
        settings.pyc
        urls.py
        urls.pyc
        wsgi.py
        wsgi.pyc
        __init__.py
        __init__.pyc
```

In my urls.py I import each views file. I write:
url(r'^home/$', views_home.home),

One thing to mention, I also import all the views from views.py to other views files, means in views_home.py I do

```
from views import *
```

Because I want some functions which are in my views.py to be available.
I have a lot of imports in the views file, some of them are django different HttpResponse type objects (Http404, HttpResponse, render etc.)
+ more external libraries.
The point is- if I will turn my views into a modules - I will create a views folder with `__init__.py` file and store my views file in this folder. How can I avoid import the same objects which are needed in every views file (like HttpResponse), in each view file in the package?
Can I write an import in `__init__.py` file that will be imported for all the files in the package? (like say, HttpResponse)
I usually see the `__init__.py` file is empty, what use does it have beside telling python that the folder is a package?

Comment: They should probably be in two separate apps

Answer (score 1):

You cannot - and should not try to - "avoid" this; it is a fundamental principle in Python that all names used in a module are defined there or imported explicitly.